# Can I distribute an app for only arm64 (M1, M2) in the app store?

Tags: mac-appstore, developer-program

I moved from Intel to M1 some time ago and I am about to drop the Intel package of my program but I get this error when I try to upload to app store:

“… bundle supports arm64 but but not Intel-based Mac computers”

Is there a way to switch from Intel to arm64 for my program in the app store? My guess is that there is a checkbox somewhere that I haven't found yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple explicitly welcomes Apple Silicon only apps.

- https://developer.apple.com/macos/submit/

> You can make your app available on the Mac App Store only to Macs with an M1 chip or later. To only support Apple silicon Macs, your app must require a minimum OS version of macOS Monterey (12.0) or later, and have never supported Intel-based Macs.

Comment: Thank you, I guess my problem is "and have never supported Intel-based Macs".

Comment: Indeed. I would imagine Apple's reasoning to be that they won't allow you to withdraw support for your Intel users. However, you could provide a new Apple Silicon only version and eventually withdraw the old version, but that would be a new App Store submission, and all the marketing hassle that goes with explaining the change and handling users' expectations. Unless you have a good technical reason to not support Intel, probably better to let Apple sunset Intel hardware on their timescale.

Comment: That's a tough requirement @JohanMattsson - hopefully you're OK starting a new premium build of the app and then sunsetting the other or just keeping the Intel kicking. Hopefully you don't need to keep an intel build machine and you can cross compile over from Apple Silicon.

Comment: That requirement will presumably disappear at some point. Once all Intel-based hardware reached EOL status (likely about a year or two from now), it will no longer make any sense to impose restrictions on existing users, since those users will now be using unsupported configurations. At some point, Intel support will be completely removed from the App Store, and they’re not going to force _every_ major app out there to switch to a completely new app once Intel support ends.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It looks like the Mac ports team finally support +universal for my dependencies. It was not hard to meet the requirements of running on Mac OS for Intel. Or at least almost all deps, I will create a PR for the missing one.